# Loopback/Localhost Question

Tags: c#, client-server, localhost, tcpclient, loopback

i have a question about sockets/clients....

I just finished writing a client server program in C#. I was wondering, how do you connect to computers that have a different IP address. For instance, if i want to run a client and server seperately on two different machines, loopback (or using the localhost) won't allow for this....

Not too familiar with networking, any help would be greatly appreciated.. here is my code on the client side which deals with loopback:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to know the IP address of the server, and specify that in the client side code.

You can get your IP by typing `ipconfig /all` on the command prompt.  Note that this will only give you the connection to the local network.

If you're trying to do this over the Internet, you'll need to use a service that finds your WAN (wide-area network) IP address.  You can google for how to do that, as there is no "standard" service to do this.

If you have a router, you'll need to forward a port to the machine your service is running on.  Look up [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), and check out the documentation for your router, or call tech support.  Or google "how do I forward ports?".

Once you have your network set up, and know all your connection info, and assuming you are using `TcpListener`:

- On the server side, simply set up your `TcpListener` with [`IpAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx).  Specify any port number you like, that isn't already in use (`8888`).
- On the client side, connect to the server's IP address.  Replace `IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")` and `8888` with the port and address of the server.

Comment: Sorry, could you please re-explain this "and if you have a router, you'll need to forward a port to the machine your service is running on." I think this is what i don't quite understand how to do... thanks for the response!

Comment: BTW, while this will teach you basics, I wouldn't try to write most programs this way unless I was very picky about how the network stream looked.  Instead I'd use web services.  They are much easier to code against.

Comment: @BlueButtons: Explaining how NAT works and tech support for your router are both outside the scope of what you asked.  It doesn't really have anything to do with programming either.  You'll need to consult the documentation for the router, or call their tech support.  Find out the IP of the machine your service is running on, find out the port you used, and forward that port to that IP.  This makes it so when someone sends a packet to your router on port 8888, it will forward that directly to your server, even if your server didn't send a packet out first.

Comment: @BlueButtons: If you're doing this on your local network (not over the internet) you don't have to worry about this tho.  Just use `ipconfig /all` and find out your IP :)  No port forwarding necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! That has really helped me quite a bit :o)

Comment: @BlueButtons: Awesome :)  Did I answer all your (programming) questions?  Were you using a different type than `TcpListener` to implement the server?

Answer (score 3):

OverMars' solution is not good because 3rd party websites like ipchicken will give you your WAN IP.  Local connections will not work.  Look up NAT(network address translation) if you need more info.

Just bind to the "Any" address if you want a seperate machine to connect.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
```

Note that "Any" translates to the address "0.0.0.0".

Answer (score 2):

`127.0.0.1` is an internal address to "this computer" or device where the application is running. Each computer will have 127.0.0.1 and at least 1 other IP address on a modern network.

To find out the IP address of another Windows computer you can use `ipconfig` from the command prompt. You will get something like this:

Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
```

In this case the 10.0.0.**2** is the IP address you can use to connect to it from other computers. Like so:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.2"), 8888);  
client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
```

A Windows computer will also have a name such as `JimsPC` or `JimsPC.abc.com` that can also be used in the `TcpClient` constructor or `BeginConnect`, `Connect` methods like so.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("JimsPC", 8888);
```

or

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("JimsPC", 8888);
```

Comment: Thanks, this post clarified things even more for me. Greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Using ipconfig i found the default gateway address, and my program is having issues connecting to it. I keep getting this error: SocketException was unhandled. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ...

Comment: @BlueButtons: The default gateway address is *probably* your router.  You want the `IP Address`, which in the example's case would be `10.0.0.2`.  This of course would be a different value on your network.

Comment: +1; Good info about using the hostname of the machine.  @BlueButtons: Note that you will be able to use this "computer name" (called a `hostname`) on the local network, but not the Internet (unless you pay for [DNS services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) that make it work - usually called "registering a domain", and possibly "registering a sub-domain").

Comment: OHH! sorry, i didn't notice the subtle difference in numbers. Thanks :o)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'll bold the .2 to make it easier to read.